# Sorting numbers after letters in alphabetical order

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting

I have an array of strings. These strings begin with both letters and numbers. By using the sorted function, I can sort the numbers, then sort the strings alphabetically.

```
let tricks = [ "360", "540", "720", "Blunt", "Nose Grind", "Method Air", "360 Mute Grab", "Japan Air"]
let sortedTricks = tricks.sorted { $0.lowercased() < $1.lowercased() }
print(sortedTricks)
// ["360", "360 Mute Grab", "540", "720", "Blunt", "Japan Air", "Method Air", "Nose Grind"]
```

How would I ascending-sort letters FIRST, then ascending-sort the numbers? Ultimately, this is how I would want the above to print:

```
// ["Blunt", "Japan Air", "Method Air", "Nose Grind", "360", "360 Mute Grab", "540", "720"]
```

Comment: What about strings that don't start with the letters A-Z or the numbers 0-9?

Comment: @rmaddy - All strings should start with 0-9, A-Z, however, any other characters (if they end up in the data) should be pushed to the end. The real goal here is displaying A-Z first, then anything else (numbers, characters, etc) after the sorted letters.

Comment: In what sense are the letters "descending-sorted" in your desired output? It looks to me like Blunt and Nose Grind and so on are all in the same order as in the original input. And the numbers seem to be ascending, not descending. Your claimed desired output does not match your description at all.

Comment: @Matt, sorry about that! I was making my post while editing the playground, so I pasted two different results. I also accidentally wrote descending instead of ascending. Original post has been edited.

Comment: Well then just say `nonnumbers.sorted()` instead of `nonnumbers` in my answer below. But even then it's unclear what you're really after; the sorting of the numbers seems arbitrary to me.

Comment: You can just sort your elements, find the first element which starts with a number and move the elements to the beginning of your array:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear what you want, because your verbal description doesn't match your shown output. It's easy to achieve the shown output from the given input:

```
let tricks = [ "360", "540", "720", "Blunt", "Nose Grind", "Method Air", "360 Mute Grab", "Japan Air"]
func startsWithANumber(_ s:String) -> Bool {
    return "0123456789".contains(s.first!)
}
let nonnumbers = tricks.filter {!startsWithANumber($0)}
let numbers = tricks.filter {startsWithANumber($0)}
let result = nonnumbers + numbers.sorted()
// ["Blunt", "Nose Grind", "Method Air", "Japan Air", "360", "360 Mute Grab", "540", "720"]
```

But whether that correctly covers all possible sets of input is impossible to say, because you have not described your desired output with any clarity or rigor.

Comment: Thanks, matt! This worked perfectly! Data should only begin with 0-9 or A-Z, so this covers all bases.